# Alternative descriptions for 'refactoring' that make a manager happy?

Tags: refactoring, project-management

My boss does not ever want to hear the word *refactoring* again, because whenever he asks a person what he is working, they reply "*I'm refactoring!*"

I need to find alternative descriptions for refactoring that can make a manager happy. Thesaurus.com does not find anything for refactoring, any ideas what I should tell him when he asks what I am doing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing whatsoever to do with programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't even need to mention them that word. Just tell them you are working on the task at hand. As refactoring is normally an integral part of the development cycle (*test - code- refactor*), this is indeed (a part of the) truth.

If (s)he insists on getting more details, you can tell you are *"finalizing the solution"*, *"ensuring long term maintainability of the code"*, or - if (s)he fancies management speak - *"leveraging the synergies within the product architecture"* :-)

Comment: Also - for the most part, you shouldn't be refactoring for very long.  So if your boss is constantly getting that answer - something's truly wrong.  What might be wrong is of course your code base - and Refactoring is the answer to how to fix that - but at least consider alternatives.

Comment: @Carl, very good point indeed! Refactoring should be in a healthy balance with "productive" (from the manager's point of view) work, at least in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

say that you are optimizing coherency